# Why is it called Heat Flow, if its units are not consistent with the definition of flux

Tags: thermal-radiation, flow, thermal-conductivity

Im studing Heat Transfer and I see how they refer to the heat flux as:

$\dot{q} = \frac{\dot{Q}}{A}$

And I've seen a flux is the quantity of something transpassing an area throught its normal component. so heat flux must be:

$ \dot{q} = \dot{Q}A$

I have also read its called heat flux density. but, why the textbooks just dont call it that way?

Comment: The equation $\dot{q} = \dot{Q}A$ is incorrect if $\dot{Q}$ is the rate of heat flow through an area $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Standard definition of the term 'flux' is as follows.

If some scalar quantity (e.g. mass, energy, charge) is flowing from one place to another then the *flux* (often indicated by the letter $\bf j$) is the amount crossing a plane per unit area per unit time.

For example, if the energy of a body is $E$ and is increasing owing to a flow of energy in a beam of area $A$, with the body absorbing all of it, then the flux of energy is
$$
j = \frac{1}{A} \frac{d E}{d t}.
$$

In optics flux is often called intensity (it is power per unit area).

Sometimes the word 'flux' is used a bit more loosely and then the physical dimensions may be different from the standard definition.

Comment: Yes, it can be loose. Magnetic flux, photon flux, ... “When I use a word,’ Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, ‘it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.’ -- Lewis Carroll